# Generating a strings of random characters from an array and enabling repetition of randomly generated numbers

Tags: javascript, random

Good evening everyone,

I am trying to generate a string of 8 characters, which are randomly chosen from an array. This is what I am using:

```
var myArrayPismo = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']; 

while(myArrayPismo.length < 9){
    var randomletter = Math.ceil(Math.random()*myArrayPismo.length)
    if(myArrayPismo.indexOf(randomletter) > -1) continue;
    myArrayPismo[myArrayPismo.length] = randomletter;
}
```

Which just prints out all of the letters, for some reason.

And this is my number generating function:

```
var kodCisla = [];
while(kodCisla.length < 9){
    var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*9)
    if(kodCisla.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
    kodCisla[kodCisla.length] = randomnumber;
}
```

Which is working fine. Except I want it to be able to generate 2 or more same numbers, not just different each time.

My goal is to get a random string of letters like this: `KODlkSmQW`
and a random string of numbers that can also repeat like this: `887562327`

Any help on either of these problems would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show an example of what you are expecting as output. First you say you want random, then you say want duplicates. Also, don't round up, round down because you'll never get "A" if you round up.

Comment: added expected results

Comment: I'm still not following you. When generating randoms, there is always the possibility of a repeating value.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/actf8rf0/ you can append additional args to function for your needs (such as fixed length etc.) i put html just for presentation.

Comment: Alright I managed to solve my issue with the numbers, I just had to change the -1 to 0 in `(kodCisla.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1)`

Comment: You don't need any `if/then` logic at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function that can pluck a random element from an array would be useful here. Notice the use of `Math.floor` rather than `Math.ceil`, and the array access that comes before the return statement.

```js
function randomElement (array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]
}

var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split(''),
    result = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    result += randomElement(characters)
}
console.log(result) //=> (random 8-character string)
```

For random numbers, you can use a similar `randomInRange` function:

```js
function randomInRange (a, b) {
    a |= 0
    b |= 0
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1)) + a
}

var result = []
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    result.push(randomInRange(0, 9))
}
console.log(result) //=> (eight random digits)
```

Comment: Cheers, you can add my "solution" to the number generating problem and you will have a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `while` loop is never running because it is based on the condition that `myArrayPismo.length < 9`, which is already false because you just set it to contain all 26 letters. So, when you go to look at it later, you get all the original values. What you need is an additional array to put the generated randoms into.

Also, stay away from a `while` loop in this case because you know exactly how many times you want to loop, so use a regular `for` loop instead.

Your second array (with numbers) does this and can certainly come up with the same random twice in a row.

But, both arrays don't need to do any if/then checking before pushing the random into the array.

Finally, as I mentioned, don't use `Math.ceil` because you'll never get the first element back as a random, use `Math.floor` instead.

```js
var myArrayPismo = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']; 

var resultArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
  resultArray.push(myArrayPismo[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArrayPismo.length)]);
}

console.log(resultArray.join(""));
```